# EJB Exception, What could be causing it? Annotation? Server:GlassFish

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, ejb, javabeans

I want to create an EJB project. I try to create a database by several entities inversely. There are some errors happened, but I cannot find it just can navigate error in Property.java.  Could you guys help me have a look. Thanks!

This is a **Property.java** file:

```
    package fit5042.tutex.repository.entities;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Embedded;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

    @Entity(name = "property_bidirectional_onetomany")
    @NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Property.GET_ALL_QUERY_NAME, query = "SELECT p FROM Property p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = Property.GET_PROPERTY_SET_BY_CONTACT_PERSON, query="SELECT p FROM Property p WHERE p.contactPerson = :contactPerson")})

    public class Property implements Serializable {

    public static final String GET_ALL_QUERY_NAME = "Property.getAll";
    public static final String GET_PROPERTY_SET_BY_CONTACT_PERSON = "Property.getPropertySetByContactPerson";

    @Id
    @Column
    private int propertyId;    
    private double size;
    private int numberOfBedrooms;
    private double price;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_contactPersonId", nullable = false)
    private ContactPerson contactPerson;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<String> tags;

    public Property() {
        this.tags = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public Property(int propertyId, Address address, int numberOfBedrooms, double size, double price, ContactPerson contactPerson, Set<String> tags) {
        this.propertyId = propertyId;
        this.address = address;
        this.size = size;
        this.numberOfBedrooms = numberOfBedrooms;
        this.price = price;
        this.contactPerson = contactPerson;
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public int getPropertyId() {
        return propertyId;
    }

    public void setPropertyId(int propertyId) {
        this.propertyId = propertyId;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public double getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(double size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int getNumberOfBedrooms() {
        return numberOfBedrooms;
    }

    public void setNumberOfBedrooms(int numberOfBedrooms) {
        this.numberOfBedrooms = numberOfBedrooms;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public ContactPerson getContactPerson() {
        return contactPerson;
    }

    public void setContactPerson(ContactPerson contactPerson) {
        this.contactPerson = contactPerson;
    }

    public Set<String> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(Set<String> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Property{" + "propertyId=" + propertyId + ", size=" + size + ", numberOfBedrooms=" + numberOfBedrooms + ", price=" + price + ", address=" + address + ", contactPerson=" + contactPerson + ", tags=" + tags + '}';
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
evere:   Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [RealEstateAgencyPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class fit5042.tutex.repository.entities.Property] uses a non-entity [class java.lang.String] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field tags].
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [RealEstateAgencyPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class fit5042.tutex.repository.entities.Property] uses a non-entity [class java.lang.String] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field tags].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1954)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1945)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:322)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:152)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [RealEstateAgencyPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class fit5042.tutex.repository.entities.Property] uses a non-entity [class java.lang.String] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field tags].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:230)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class fit5042.tutex.repository.entities.Property] uses a non-entity [class java.lang.String] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field tags].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.nonEntityTargetInRelationship(ValidationException.java:1378)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.RelationshipAccessor.getReferenceDescriptor(RelationshipAccessor.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.RelationshipAccessor.processJoinTable(RelationshipAccessor.java:720)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.OneToManyAccessor.processManyToManyMapping(OneToManyAccessor.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.OneToManyAccessor.process(OneToManyAccessor.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processOwningRelationshipAccessors(MetadataProject.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage3(MetadataProject.java:1833)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1869)
    ... 56 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this fragment:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<String> tags;
```

It does not make sense to try to set a relation with `String` class.

Comment: So how to fix this bug to make TAG table be created successfully?

Comment: You need to use @ElementCollection for that